# I can't understand why this sequence of functions does not have more than one pointwise limit?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am given the sequence of functions $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, where

$f_k(x)= \frac{x^k}{1+x^k}$, $k\in\mathbb{N},x\in[0,\infty)$

I need to compute the pointwise limit of it. I note that it is bounded, as $$f_k(x)\leq \frac{x^k}{x^k}=1$$
Surely for $0\leq x<1$ we have $f_k(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and for $k>1$ we have $f_k(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$? I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: So you have concluded that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x^k}{1+x^k}=\begin{cases}0 & 0\le x \lt 1\\\frac{1}{2} & x=1 \\ 1 & x\gt 1\end{cases}$$ which is correct. What problem do you see here? A sequence of continuous functions does not need to converge to a continuous function.

Comment: Everything is understood in pointwise sense: a sequence of functions has at most one pointwise limit at each point. So this is exactly the same as the claim that a sequence of real numbers (or any your favorite elements in a Hausdorff space) has at most one limit.

Comment: The question in my problem sheet asked me to compute the pointwise limit - I presumed that there was only one limit therefore - would the answer by @user8734617 be what I should write?

Comment: Yes, the pointwise limit of functions $f_k(x)$ is still a *function* of $x$. It maps $x$ to the limit of the sequence $f_k(x)$ for *that* $x$.

Comment: The formula @user8734617 gives is a single function of $x$.  It is described piecewise, but that does not mean it is more than one function.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense. Could you put this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer. Also, how can I show that it does not uniformly converge at $x=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence of functions $f_k(x)$ converges pointwise to a function $f(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$, given by:

$$f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=\begin{cases}0 & 0\le x \lt 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} & x=1 \\ 1 & x\gt 1\end{cases}$$

Because $f_k$ are all continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $f$ is discontinuous, it follows that those functions converge to $f$ (when $k\to\infty$) only pointwise, but not uniformly, because otherwise their limit $f$ would be continuous as well, as per [Uniform limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem). Actually, this sequence of functions doesn't converge uniformly on any interval containing $x=1$, for the same reason.

As for the additional question you added in the comments:

Let $b\gt 1$. All the functions $f_k(x)=\frac{x^k}{1+x^k}\lt 1$ are increasing in $x$. Thus, if, for given $\varepsilon\gt 0$ we can find $k_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $|1-f_k(b)|=1-f_k(b)\lt\varepsilon$ for all $k\gt k_0$ (which we can, because of the pointwise convergence at $b$), then, for all $x\ge b$, we will have $|1-f_k(x)|=1-f_k(x)\le 1-f_k(b)\lt \varepsilon$ for all $k\gt k_0$ too, which means that the choice of $k_0$ is independent on $x$, and so the convergence of $f_k$ to $f$ when $k\to\infty$ is uniform on any interval $[b,\infty)$ for $b\gt 1$.

Comment: Thanks. How can I show that this function does not uniformly converge at $x=1$?

Comment: @BenHarvey How did you define uniform convergence *at a point*? I would like to answer with respect to a definition that you use.

Comment: I don't believe we have defined uniform converge at a point. The question merely asks us to show that it converges uniformly for $x\in [b,\infty), b>1$ and asks us to show why it doesn't converge uniformly for $x \in [1,\infty)$

Comment: I've already updated my answer. It is enough for an interval to contain $1$, and on that interval the functions $f_k$ are still continuous, and converge to $f$ pointwise, and $f$ is not continuous - hence the convergence is not uniform. As for proving that it *does* converge uniformly on $[b, \infty)$ where $b\gt 1$ - I see that question for the first time today in your comment... Would be fair to post the whole question at once and not add small bits all the time.

Answer (score 0):

These functions do not converge uniformly, so their pointwise limit can be discontinuous.